# Save Integers with the Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a quick question about the Scanner class.
I had an idea to make a simple program that starts to count all the numbers I write in, but if it goes over a limit it should stop.
This is not the problem....

The problem is that the FIRST number you write in should be the number that tells the program how many numbers it will be counting.

For an example.

When the program starts, I will write in for example :

3
100
234
546

Sum: 880.

and the output should be the sum of 100+234+546.
The number 3 in the beginning just told the program that it is 3 numbers that it should read. I don't understand how to make the first number the number that tells the program how many numbers it should be in the input before it starts to count.

Comment: show some code / own efforts please. You've been with us a while - so you should know?!

Comment: What have you got so far? You could read an int and use it in a condition of a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
void yourMethod()
{
     int sum=0;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int conut=scan.next();
     for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
     {
       sum=sum+scan.next();
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can do something like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = scan.nextInt();  //First number is the count of numbers
//line below loops for you and sums at the end
int sum = IntStream.range(0, N).map(i -> scan.nextInt()).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the first number in a variable called `counter` or similar, and then execute a loop (`for`, `while`) for `counter` times, in each iteration you will read the next number and sum them. The algorithm seems very straightforward to create code from it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = scan.nextInt();

while(count>0){
   //your logic
   count--;
}
```